# jquery scrollbars not appearing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css

I have a pop up window that is not showing scrollbars when opened. Here is my code:

```
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow = window.open(url, 'name', 'height=800,width=1000' , 'scrollbars=1' );
    if (window.focus) { newwindow.focus() }
    return false;
}
```

I read somewhere that if the position:absolute; characteristic is placed here, then scrollbars do not appear. But in this case the position is relative so why are there no scrollbars appearing in Firefox for me then?

Comment: maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163275/how-to-use-window-open-to-create-with-scrollbar-in-firefox

Comment: tried that, didnt work

Comment: There's no jQuery here. Removed that and added the javascript tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the arguments except the URL and the window name should be provided as a *single* string:

```
'height=800,width=1000,scrollbars=1'
```

You should get scroll bars by default though, but only if there is enough content to cause the page to scroll (and only if the browser will render scroll bars in the first place).

Comment: ok that adds the scrollbars but makes the open page into a new tab instead of a popout window. Is there more code I need to add to make it popout instead of making a new tab?

Comment: I get a new window, not a new tab when I run that.

Comment: makes a new tab for me for some reason, strange

Comment: this Makes Opens a New Tab\