# javascript onclick window.open not giving scroll bars in firefox

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to hard code a javascript pop-up window into an a tag with the following code:

```
<a target="_blank" style="font-style:italic;" href="/price-match-guarantee_a/289.htm" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'mywin', 'left=20,top=20,width=500,height=500,toolbar=1,resizable=0'); return false;" >We'll Beat It!</a>
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, but when I open the pop-up in firefox or IE, there are no scroll bars added to the pop-up window. How can I remedy this?

Thanks! - You can view a page with the pop-up link at:
http://xlevj.jyetp.servertrust.com/Ibanez-Rgir28Fe-Iron-Lbl-8-String-Electric-Guitar-p/951.htm

The links are titled "We'll beat it!" and "Let Us Find One For You!"

Alex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163275/

Comment: Thanks my man. Apparently I suck at searching. I tried... really!

Comment: `scrollbars=1` I believe this affects IE, Firefox and Opera only.